# Handeling bash command in c#

Tags: c#, bash, docker, api

I'm looking for some information on handling bash commands. I'm currently in the designing and analysis phase so I don't have code yet, but I'm looking for some options and information.

So me and a friend wanted to build a remote application that can monitor and handle our game servers, currently minecraft but other games like factorio, don't strave together,.. will be added too.

Our intention is to be able to upload new mods and remove mods aswell as updating mods, and getting some information for statistics and stuff.

So I tought maybe I should deploy an api on the minecraft server (running locally in a vm) this way I can get information about the server

Preferably I like to run the app inside docker, however docker is made to disable to handle commands, and other stuff since I also need to be able to copy files to a certain directory.

My minecraft sh script is made so it autostarts when the server crashes. However when updating mods I need to be able to do a sudo systemctl restart minecraft.service to make those changes.

Docker isn't reallly necessary, I can just use nginx aswell.

Any ideas on how to handle those commands aswell as copying data?
my idea is to upload a file via the api and the api will handle the copying pasting and removing.

The app itself: the frontend will be available on the internet somy friends can monitor asweel of course behind authorization.

I could create it so the restart command can only be handled by the admin and the admin can only be logged in locally meaning in my lan network rather the the wan network.

Any ideas for best practices to handle this?

Comment: Bash is the unix shell which is equivalent to cmd.exe on windows.  So you should be able to use the Process Class for running commands in c#.  See : https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/10/29/the-net-process-class-on-linux?force_isolation=true#

Comment: Yes, but I assume I cannot directly to this in docker. I need to be able then to run on the host. should this be possible with docker exec?

Comment: Docker is creating an HTTP connection from a client to a server.  Bash are commands that are going to run either at client or server.  Docker is going to have a controller at client and server and the Process class will be called from the controller code.

Comment: See following : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/?force_isolation=true